# Formula will directly Match the Values Then paste Result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have created a formula by using helping column in `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` to Paste the Result in `Sheet3`.

I have `Country` and `IDs` in `Sheet1` and in `Sheet2` `Amount` and `ID`.

and in `Sheet3` I have Unique `Countries`  so i want to match `Sheet2` `IDs` by `Sheet1` to know the `Country Name`. When `Country Name` matches then `Sum` the Amount in `Sheet3`.

the formulas i have been using are mentioned below. But all i want is to get the result directly without any helping Columns.

any help will be highly appreciated.

```
=VLOOKUP(J2,Sheet1!$I$2:$J$26,2,0)
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!$E$2:$E$26,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$26,A2)
```

Below is attached sheet where i have done this calculation.

[Linked Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Viv50qbo1fFW_sGcMpaZQ7qLeu8GkMXDILSr7WBZmXU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use SUMPRODUCT with a SUMIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Sheet2!E:E,Sheet2!J:J,Sheet1!I2:I26)*(Sheet1!D2:D26=A2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Scott Craner for the help, one more favor please if i want to add date Column how it would be done. `G2:G1000,">="&$F$1,G2:G1000,"<="&$G$1`

Answer (score 0):

### SOLVED! (2 ways)

**HIGH-LEVEL**

- Method A & B incompatible in Google Sheets (tested / work in Excel)
- Screenshots below demonstrate reference/links

**FUNCTIONS**

Method A (double if statement - proposed):

```
=SUM(IF($A$3:$A$27=IF($B$32:$B$56=F3,$A$32:$A$56,""),$B$3:$B$27,0))
```

- Simplest
- Does not require Office 365

Method B (index + filter, requires Office 365)

```
=SUM(INDEX($B$3:$B$27,MATCH(FILTER($A$32:$A$56,$B$32:$B$56=F3),$A$3:$A$27,0)))
```

- Relatively complex

- Individual components (e.g. filter, index etc.) may provide (purposeful) standalone data

SCREENSHOT:

[image: Application & reconciliation - Methods A & B]

Comment: Anytime   (at least 15 chars)